# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS error when using Laravel and S3

Tags: php, laravel, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm just having a snag with the Storage facade in Laravel 5.1 when using S3.

I have the following code in a controller:

```
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $filename = date('d-m-Y').'_'.$request->get('author').'.'.$extension;
    Storage::put($filename, $file);
```

However I get the following error:

```
S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 162: Error executing "HeadObject" on "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED]/10-06-2015_my%20file.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS'
```

I have cURL installed along with php5-curl on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using HHVM 3.7.

Comment: Which curl version are you using? Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, it was introduced in 7.19.4

Comment: curl_version(); says I'm using version 7.35.0

Answer (score 1):

Didn't initially notice you are using hhvm. It's not supported.

See

- https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3737
- https://github.com/fruux/sabre-http/pull/14

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John, hhvm 3.7 (stable) doesn't support curl setopt. I upgraded to nightly builds (3.8.0-dev) and it worked! Probably not a good solution for production environments however.